# How to 'reduce' repetitions in a list

Tags: python, loops, repeat

I am having trouble thinking of the most efficient way to reduce repetitions in a list.

```
a = ['x','x','x','y','y','y','z','z','z','x','x','x','z','z','z','z','z','z']
```

The desired output (if I reduce sets of 3) would be:

```
a_reduced = ['x','y','z','x','z','z']
```

I was thinking of looping through each element and do a '[i] and [i+1] and [i+2] condition' thing, but I am sure there is a super easy and efficient way to achieve this and that I am just missing something. Assist please, thanks!

Comment: While not exactly an answer, you can totally prune it with `set`, which would give `a_set = ('x', 'y', 'z')`

Comment: Could you explain the question better? I would assume the "reduced" list would just be `['x', 'y', 'z']`?

Comment: If they are always in sets of 3 you could simply do `a[::3]` which will just grab every 3rd element from the list. Otherwise you will probably want to use `itertools.groupby` to solve this. I'm not clear as to what you specifically want.

Comment: Thanks Thimble, this was exactly the idea I was looking for!

Comment: @Thimble perhaps you should make an answer to that effect if the OP is happy with it... as it appears it's absolutely nothing to do with "repetitions"

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the advice, done. Wasn't sure as to what result OP was looking for. However hopefully it will help someone out searching for a similar answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your repetitions are always in sets of 3 you could simply do:

```
a = ['x','x','x','y','y','y','z','z','z','x','x','x','z','z','z','z','z','z']
a_reduced = a[::3]
print a_reduced
>>>['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'z', 'z']
```

This will just grab every 3rd element from the list. Again, this is assuming your list is always in sets of 3. It will be skewed if they are not. Otherwise you if you just want to condense all of the unique repetitions as they go you can use `itertools.groupby` which will do just that:

```
from itertools import groupby
a = ['x','x','x','y','y','y','z','z','z','x','x','x','z','z','z','z','z','z']
a_reduced = [item[0] for item in groupby(a)]
print a_reduced
>>>['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'z']
```